# Multiplication of a matrix with a complex vector

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

A simple question. I'm aware that inner product over the complex numbers $\mathbb C$ involves the conjugate of one of the numbers.

But what about Matrix multiplication? For instance, if I have a real matrix M, and a complex vector $v$, if I would like to multiply $v$ by $M$, whould I have to take the conjugate of $v$, that is :

$$\left( Mv\right)_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} M_{i,j} \cdot \bar{v_j} $$

The reason I'm asking, is because MATLAB/Octave, is calculating the multiplication like this. And if so, why is it true ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Octave does not calculate matrix multiplication like that. Show what you have done to conclude this.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

But when you executed:
a = ones(2,2);
a * [1+i,1]'

You get: [2-i;2-i]

Which means, it takes the conjugate.

Comment: Matlab also doesn't...

Comment: That just computes a matrix of ones.

Comment: It means that the ' operator takes the complex conjugate. Just do [1+i,i]'.

Comment: Also in Matlab, try to execute:

 a = ones(2,2); a * [1+i,1]' 
You get: [2-i;2-i]

Comment: I understand both, you are misunderstanding how ' works. Multiplication works are normal.

Comment: Right! The ' operator takes to complex conjugate. Thanks a lot copper !!

Comment: @Satya you can type column vector using `;` instead of `,`. Also transpose is `.'`.